# when running program it has me enter two lines after name? help please

Tags: c++, getline

my program seems to want to enter two inputs for name variable instead of just entering one thing and moving on to phone number?

i'm sure its simple but can someone help me fix this please? is it something it do with the getline?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//define Car struct
struct Speaker
{
string name;
string phoneNumber;
string emailAddress;
string theme;
double fee;
};

Speaker *getSpeaker();


int main()
{
Speaker thespeaker;
thespeaker = *getSpeaker();
cout << "The speaker entered is!" << endl;
cout << thespeaker.name << endl;
cout << "phone number: " << thespeaker.phoneNumber << endl;
cout << "email: " << thespeaker.emailAddress << endl;
cout << "theme: " << thespeaker.theme << endl;
cout << "fees: " << thespeaker.fee << endl;
}

Speaker *getSpeaker()
{
Speaker *theSpeaker;
theSpeaker = new Speaker;
cout << "Please enter Speakers information" << endl;
cout << "name: " ;
getline(cin, theSpeaker->name);
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cin.clear();
cout << theSpeaker->name;
cout << "\nphone number: ";
cin >> theSpeaker->phoneNumber;
cout << "\nEmail Address: ";
cin >> theSpeaker->emailAddress;
cout << "\nTheme: ";
cin >> theSpeaker->theme;
cout << "\nFee: ";
cin >>theSpeaker->fee;

return theSpeaker;
}
```

Comment: This leaks memory - take out all the `*` to fix that :)  (and change `->` to `.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for `cin.ignore();` 
Simply write it as:

```
Speaker *getSpeaker()
{
Speaker *theSpeaker;
theSpeaker = new Speaker;
cout << "Please enter Speakers information" << endl;
cout << "name: " ;
getline(cin, theSpeaker->name);
cout << theSpeaker->name;
cout << "\nphone number: ";
cin >> theSpeaker->phoneNumber;
cout << "\nEmail Address: ";
cin >> theSpeaker->emailAddress;
cout << "\nTheme: ";
cin >> theSpeaker->theme;
cout << "\nFee: ";
cin >>theSpeaker->fee;

return theSpeaker;
}
```